# Primefaces DataScroller Loader facet not working

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces datascroller containing list of accordionPanels in it.  I am using 'loader' facet for lazy loading.  On clicking more the next chunk of data is listed.  The problem is, if I click a commandButton inside the accordion tab, the 'loader' facet stops working.  This is my code:

```xml
<p:dataScroller layout="block"
value="#{bean.mainList}" var="manvo" chunkSize="3" lazy="true">
<f:facet name="loader">
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="More" process="@this"  />
</f:facet>
<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="1" dynamic="true"  scrollHeight="auto">
    <p:tab title="#{manvo.releaseName} >> #{manvo.tcName}">
        <p:commandButton value="TestIt" actionListener="#{bean.testSubmit()}" update="@form"/>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```